# Java regex to groovy

Tags: java, regex, groovy, soapui

I got this code in java which replaces with white space the regex:

```
private static final String SCRUB_REGEX = "[\\<\\>\\\"\\'\\(\\)\\\\\\n\\r\\f]";
private static final String SCRUB_REPLACEMENT = " ";
String trim = value.replaceAll(SCRUB_REGEX, SCRUB_REPLACEMENT).trim();
```

I am trying to use this in a groovy script of SoapUI and it doesn't seem to actually trim. Does groovy not recognize the java regex?

```
temp =testStep.getPropertyValue(sorted).replaceAll("[\\<\\>\\\"\\'\\(\\)\\\\\\n\\r\\f]", " ").trim()
```

I have done import to import java.util.regex.*

Comment: what is the text that you are working with?

Comment: While it's not idiomatic Groovy, what you have written should work, as far as I can see. Could you add an example of an input string, along with expected and actual outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `import java.util.regex.*`

Slash strings make things easier:

```
String SCRUB_REGEX = /[<>"'()\\\n\r\f]/
String SCRUB_REPLACEMENT = ' '
String trim = value.replaceAll(SCRUB_REGEX, SCRUB_REPLACEMENT).trim();
```

So this will replace all of:

- `<`
- `>`
- `"`
- `'`
- `(`
- `)`
- `\`
- `\n`
- `\r`
- `\f`

With a space

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without input and output, but a few comments:

1. You don't need to escape special characters when inside a character class (enclosed between square brackets `[]`). You still need to use a single escape for special constructs. You can use the following pattern instead:

`"[<>\"'()\n\r\f]"`

2. You might want to replace multiple occurrences of your characters with only one whitespace. In which case, add a quantifier, as such:

`"[<>\"'()\n\r\f]+"`

3. `String.trim` only trims your given `String`'s beginning and end off whitespace. Anything in the middle will not be trimmed. If the `String` is entirely whitespace, then `trim` will return an empty `String`.

Comment: thanks guys i couldn't find any better explanation in google.